group numbering when one of them is facultative
I'm coding in Rust but I suppose that my question is kind of language-independent.
For a regex field_name1 (\d+)( facultative_field \d+)? field_name2 (\d+) I'd like to get the values of fields 1 and 2. But number/rank of the group dedicated to field 2 depends on the presence of the group of the facultative field (which makes the extract method panic).
What's the idiomatic way to get the value of field 2?

You can use named groups.

Group numbering isn't affected by whether it's optional. The optional field will always be field 2, whether it matches or not.

The non-optional fields will always be group 1 and 3.

Well no: the extract method panics

A regex such as field_name1 (\d+)((?: facultative_field \d+)?) field_name2 (\d+) should work. The change is to put the optional part in a non-capturing group with (?: ... ). Then enclose that whole thing in a capturing group. Thus if the facultative_field part is missing then capture group 2 will be empty. Capture group 3 will allways hold the final digits.

Why is this necessary? If the optional pattern doesn't match, it will simply be an empty string in the result. You don't need to wrap it in another group.

Because the extract method panics
